# Why did I have to use backticks around the table name in my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, backticks

As far as I have read, backticks are not required around, for example, table names in queries: ("INSERT INTO table_name...."). In addition, to my knowledge, underscores are perfectly acceptable syntax to use in names: foo_bar. My question then is, why did this query fail:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO quick_links WHERE ...etc");
```

when this query worked perfectly:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `quick_links` WHERE ...etc");
```

Are "quick" or "links" reserved words??? I didn't think so, but then again, I'm fairly new to MySQL, so I apologize. Also,is using backticks necessary in certain "Storage Engines" (referencing phpMyAdmin for the terminology)? I happen to be using "InnoDB" if that makes any difference.

Thanks for the answers, I'm new to MySQL, and I like to make sure I understand nuances like these.

My full query was this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `quick_links` VALUES (
    '$user_id', '$ql_name', '$ql_url', '$ql_img'
)");
```

$ql_url and $ql_name were obtained via $_POST and then sanitized with trim and mysql_real_escape_string before being used in the query. $ql_img is simply a url referring to a directory in which a thumbnail is uploaded, and $user_id is there to, well, identify the particular user who is logged in. Both queries were exactly the same, literally, except for the backticks around the table_name.

Comment: can you show the whole query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Backtick are only used to escape **[MySQL Reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**. They are optional if didn't use any of the *reserved keywords* provided that the tableNames or columnNames used has `no spaces` on it.

This **[page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)** tells the allowable characters to be used in schema.

Comment: Consider how severely you would beat someone who created a table called "has spaces"

Comment: Do we need to use them in PostgreSQL also?